# Extending class from argument

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

In an ideal world I would be able to import `google` and extend it as well as use it within my class.

```
import google from 'google'

class GoogleMapsPopover extends google.maps.OverlayView{
  constructor ({point, map}) {
    this.bounds_ = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(point, point)
    this.map_ = map
    this.div_ = null
    this.setMap(map)
  }
}
```

However I would like to pass `google` in as an argument to the `GoogleMapsPopover` class.

You can't have `super` without extending like this:

```
class GoogleMapsPopover {
  constructor ({google, point, map}) {
    super(google.maps.OverlayView)
    this.google = google
    this.bounds_ = new this.google.maps.LatLngBounds(point, point)
    this.map_ = map
    this.div_ = null
    this.setMap(map)
  }
}
```

You can't set the value of `this` like this:

```
class GoogleMapsPopover {
  constructor ({google, point, map}) {
    this = google.maps.OverlayView
    this.google = google
    this.bounds_ = new this.google.maps.LatLngBounds(point, point)
    this.map_ = map
    this.div_ = null
    this.setMap(map)
  }
}
```

The only alternative I can think of is wrapping the class within a function and which is kind of hacky.

Something like this:

```
export const getGoogleMapsPopoverClass = (google) => {
  return class GoogleMapsPopover extends google.maps.OverlayView {
    constructor ({point, map}) {
      super()
      this.bounds_ = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(point, point)
      this.map_ = map
      this.div_ = null
      this.setMap(map)
    }
  }
}

const GoogleMapsPopover = getGoogleMapsPopoverClass(google)
```

Comment: JS "classes" don't look too convenient. Why not use `Object.create`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you post an example?

Comment: What exactly keeps you from implementing it as in the ideal world? Why would you "*like to pass google in as an argument*"? No, it makes no sense to pass the superclass as an argument into the constructor.